# Why ajax put FormData into request.data instead of request.files?

Tags: ajax, flask, upload

Flask, and I want to upload an image file through an AJAX call in HTML.

I wrote this Javascript:

```
function mysubmit(input){
    var file_input = document.getElementById('file-input-left');
    var form_data = new FormData();
    var file = file_input.files[0];
    alert(file);
    form_data.append('file', file);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/calc_full_result',
        data: form_data,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        async: false,
        success: function(data){
            alert('Success!');
        },
    });
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="image-holder">
    <form action="/calc_full_result" id="upload-form-left" name="form-left" method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
    <div class="image-holder-left">
        <div class="image-upload">
        {% if img_left %}
        <label id="upload-left-label" for="file-input-left"><img id="left-image" src="data:image/png;base64, {{img_left}}"/></label>
        {% else %}
        <label id="upload-left-label" for="file-input-left"><img id="left-image" src="{{url_for('static', filename='upload_fill.png')}}" /></label>
        {% endif %}
        <input id="file-input-left" type=file name=file onchange="mysubmit(this)"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <form action="/calc_full_result" id="upload-form-right" name="form-right" method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
    <div class="image-holder-right">
        <div class="image-upload">
        {% if img_right %}
        <label id="upload-right-label" for="file-input-right"><img id="right-image" src="data:image/png;base64, {{img_right}}"/></label>
        {% else %}
        <label id="upload-right-label" for="file-input-right"><img id="right-image" src="{{url_for('static', filename='upload_fill.png')}}"/></label>
        {% endif %}
        <input id="file-input-right" type=file name=file onchange="mysubmit(this)"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Then in app.py:

```py
@app.route('/calc_full_result', methods=['POST'])
def calc_full_result():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        return jsonify(result="suc")
```

But I cannot get the object file, it's always empty and cannot be saved. When I check the request I can see `len(request.data)` is almost the size of image file.
I wonder why `request.files` is empty and how to save the file in `request.data`? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
data: new FormData(document.getElementById('upload-form-left'))
```

Comment: It does not work for me.No matter new FormData from input or form, it's the same.

Comment: why do you have `async: false`?

Comment: actually I learned this code from a demo, and setting async to true will help? I'd like to take a try, thank you first

Comment: Well ajax is vast majority of the time asynchronous, and for file upload, async false makes no sense. Actually synchronous xhr are [deprecated](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#sync-warning). Have you tried to save the file in your controller using `file.save ("/some/path/file")`?